# como puedo actualizar varios rows dinamicamente

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi controlador y quiero actualizar url_requisitos con diferentes valores de mis inputs. De actualizar, actualiza, pero solo con el valor del primer input.

```
    public function actualizar_archivos(UpdateTramites $UpdateTramites,Request $request,$recepcion_tramite_id){
    $this->modelupdate= $UpdateTramites ;
            $UpdateTramites=$this->modelupdate->find($recepcion_tramite_id);
                if(!$UpdateTramites){
                    return response("Datos no encontrados");
                }
                try{
                    $datos=$request->all();
                    $UpdateTramites->fill($datos)->save();
                    return response("Datos Actualizados");    
                }catch(\Throwable $th){
                      throw $th;  
                }
        }
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Cuál controlador? Qué filas de qué tabla? Añade toda la info como texto para que puedas recibir ayuda oportuna. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: No repitas el mismo ID **nunca** en HTML. En este caso usa clases para que las actualice todas.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Por favor, prestá atención cuando redactás o editás la pregunta, ya que agregabas ruido innecesario. Por cierto, los snippets son solo para código HTML + CSS + JS. Dale formato al código agregando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tal código.